# GCC links symbols for an unreachable switch-case statement

Tags: c, gcc, compiler-optimization, dead-code

I'm writing a code with C that uses the factory pattern to initialize objects for specific interfaces. It simply assigns functions to related pointers according to the type. My interface and main application look like this:

```
typedef enum
{
    INTF_DEV_FOO,
    INTF_DEV_BAR
} intf_dev_t;

typedef struct
{
    int (*exec)(void);
} intf_t;
```

```
static void intf_select_foo(intf_t* intf)
{
    intf->exec = foo_exec;
}

static void intf_select_bar(intf_t* intf)
{
    intf->exec = bar_exec;
}

int intf_init(intf_t* intf, intf_dev_t dev)
{
    int result = 0;

    switch (dev)
    {
        case INTF_DEV_FOO:
            intf_select_foo(intf);
            break;
        case INTF_DEV_BAR:
            intf_select_bar(intf);
            break;
        default:
            result = -1;
    }

    return result;
}
```

```
int main(void)
{
    intf_t intf = {0};

    intf_init(&intf, INTF_DEV_FOO);
    intf.exec();

    return 0;
}
```

I was expecting to see `bar` would be discarded since its statement is unreachable. But when I looked at the assembly code of the output, both of the functions were linked. Here is the disassembly code:

```
004077e0 <_bar_exec>:
  4077e0:   83 ec 1c                sub    $0x1c,%esp
  4077e3:   c7 04 24 84 90 40 00    movl   $0x409084,(%esp)
  4077ea:   e8 b9 fc ff ff          call   4074a8 <_puts>
  4077ef:   31 c0                   xor    %eax,%eax
  4077f1:   83 c4 1c                add    $0x1c,%esp
  4077f4:   c3                      ret

00407800 <_foo_exec>:
  407800:   83 ec 1c                sub    $0x1c,%esp
  407803:   c7 04 24 90 90 40 00    movl   $0x409090,(%esp)
  40780a:   e8 99 fc ff ff          call   4074a8 <_puts>
  40780f:   31 c0                   xor    %eax,%eax
  407811:   83 c4 1c                add    $0x1c,%esp
  407814:   c3                      ret

00407820 <_intf_init>:
  407820:   8b 44 24 08             mov    0x8(%esp),%eax
  407824:   85 c0                   test   %eax,%eax
  407826:   74 1e                   je     407846 <_intf_init+0x26>
  407828:   83 f8 01                cmp    $0x1,%eax
  40782b:   75 13                   jne    407840 <_intf_init+0x20>
  40782d:   8b 44 24 04             mov    0x4(%esp),%eax
  407831:   c7 00 e0 77 40 00       movl   $0x4077e0,(%eax)
  407837:   31 c0                   xor    %eax,%eax
  407839:   c3                      ret    
  40783a:   8d b6 00 00 00 00       lea    0x0(%esi),%esi
  407840:   b8 ff ff ff ff          mov    $0xffffffff,%eax
  407845:   c3                      ret    
  407846:   8b 44 24 04             mov    0x4(%esp),%eax
  40784a:   c7 00 00 78 40 00       movl   $0x407800,(%eax)
  407850:   31 c0                   xor    %eax,%eax
  407852:   c3                      ret
```

As far as I know, it should be part of the dead code elimination optimization. But when I add another module with another case statement, my code size is getting bigger and I see its symbols both in the map file and the assembly code.

I'm compiling my code with GCC 8.0.0 on Windows. Here is my compilation setting:

```
gcc *c -O3 -fdata-sections -ffunction-sections -o dce -Xlinker -Map='dce.map' '-Wl,--gc-sections'
```

Am I missing something here or is this related to the optimization capabilities?

Comment: Research the topic: _link-time optimization_. Your whole code can be just optimized to `int main() { foo_exec(); }` anyway.

Comment: Try adding `-flto` to both compile and link https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Optimize-Options.html

Comment: Is all the code in a single translation unit? Otherwise neither the compiler nor the linker can really remove the function, since neither knows if the function will be called at run-time or not.

Comment: Where are `foo_exec`and `bar_exec`?

Comment: @RichardCritten `-flto` solved the issue. Thank you.

Comment: @MarcoBonelli that doesn't tell us anything , it could be one `.c` file or multiple